# How can I put Sticker inside a Telegram bot message?

Tags: php, request, telegram-bot

I'm writing a Telegram bot and I want it to send a sticker INSIDE the message.

```
$file_id="CAADAgADqAIAAkcVaAllGKpjZDCAgQI";
$send_text = "Test";

$send_sticker=file_get_contents('https://api.telegram.org/bot'.$bot_token.'/sendSticker?chat_id='.$user_id.'&sticker='.$file_id);

$send_message=file_get_contents('https://api.telegram.org/bot'.$bot_token.'/sendMessage?chat_id='.$user_id.'&text='.$send_text);
```

This code is working, it sends a sticker, and afterward it sends a message. However, can I send any sticker or smiley inside a message?

Comment: I've never seen a sticker within a message. They always have a message on their own.

Comment: A smiley can be good for me also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use sticker inside of message with text.
But you can use emoji (smiley), the easiest way to do it is to choose emojis that you need in Telegram (when you are composing message) and then just copy them and paste too your code. More difficult but theoretically more correct way is to use UTF-codes of emoji (you can find them on Internet)

Comment: Thanks, it worked: $text_message = " \xf0\x9f\x98\x81 ";